# Access Property file : Java and Linux

Tags: java, linux, log4j

this is my folder structure

```
proj    
   --src   
   --config    
   --bin
```

In linux its

```
/home/proj/src
/home/proj/config
```

My config folder contains log4j property file.

I am trying to execute my java class in linux.

This is how I am accessing it in my java class (this is surely wrong)

```
String propFile = "/../config/Log4jprop.properties";
ClassLoader systemClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
URL logPropFile = systemClassLoader.getResource(propFile);
PropertyConfigurator.configure(logPropFile);
```

I need to be able to access my property file from my class in linux.

A portion of my command is as follows

```
java -classpath /home/proj/config/Log4jprop.properties:./ Start
```

How can I ensure that the log property file is read?

Comment: If the file is in the classpath, then you don't need to specify the path, just filename will do, if you are using classloader to load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions could be:

1. Remove your "Property file reading code at all"
2. Run your command with

   java -Dlog4j.configuration=/home/proj/config/Log4jprop.properties:./ Start

Alternatively:

1. Rename your properties file to log4j.properties
2. add it into your classpath

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the path of the properties file, then this is the option:

```
props.load(new FileReader("/home/whatever/config.properties"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, after setting the classpath to "proj" folder.

```
    FileInputStream str = null;
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try 
    {
        str = new FileInputStream("config/Log4jprop.properties");
        prop.load(str);
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(prop);
    }catch( IOException ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if( str != null ) {
            try {
                str.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, then I have to execute this code from the parent folder of config.I want a relative path,for eg - go to the root->config and read the prop file

Comment: Here "config/Log4jprop.properties" is the relative path to the properties file and it's relative to the classpath.